# How do I get the sampling rate of a canvas element?

Tags: html5-canvas

I am currently investigating preprocessing for on-line handwriting recognition (see http://write-math.com). One interesting property of input devices is the sampling rate, that means the rate at which I get `onmousemove` and similar events.

I can record them and see the time delta between two events is varies from 1.00 ms - 700.00 ms, but is in average 27.34 ms [for this recording](http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/view/?raw_data_id=12765).

(sampling rate is measured in Points / second. So the sampling rate would be [image] or for the average case [image])

Is there any possibility to get this information from the client directly? Are there devices where the sampling rate is known? How does Javascript internally decide how often to fire those events? Can the "event firing rate" be increased / decreased?

Answer (score 1):

Mousemove firing rates for a particular browser are stable over a sufficient sample size, but the firing rate of any individual mouse event is affected by non-canvas activities (garbage collection, background tasks, etc).

I don't know of any browser that allows adjustment of the mousemove timing--all internally defined.

Interesting project!

Comment: Several more thoughts: You could throw out some values that are high and low outside your mean 27.34 average firing rate. Or if those values are critical you could adjust the outside values by re-assigning them a 27.34 time (assume the abnormal value was non-canvas related and requires "fixing").  If you need greater accuracy (not precision) then you can use the high-resolution `performance` timer if the browser supports it.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you :-) I don't think I need higher accuracy. But the changing time delta (especially from the first point to the second point) is sometimes a problem. Especially for characters that start round (like "O"). I can somehow deal with this problem by using cubic splines, but there is a significant difference between the time delta of the first two points to the rest (in Google Chrome).

Comment: In Chrome I've experienced bad timings between time0 and time1.